# Passing variable in viewDidLoad() or ViewDidAppear() to button action

Tags: swift

I have a complex variable that I look up from a Firestore Document but that is not important.  It works perfectly in either `viewDidLoad` or `viewDidAppear`.  I can print it to verify the variable has the correct value.

```
let q1 = data!["q1"]! as? Bool ?? true
```

When I call the variable in the `if` statement in the button action I get the following error:

> Use of unresolved identifier 'q1'

```
print(q1)
```

But `print(q1)` works perfectly if run in the `viewDidAppear`.

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?  How can I pass a variable from viewDidLoad to the button action?

Comment: Please show relevant code. Include enough context. But it sounds like you have a local variable in one function that you are trying to access in another function.

Comment: Probably some of what I'm seeing is simply typos, but there's a lot that isn't. (1) What is the error? What is `pbht`? (2) Can you describe more specifically what it is you are trying to do? A button action can most definitely access variables that are not from the sender - but maybe you are running into a variable scope issue - or maybe it's latency. two lines of code, one of which is a `print` statement doesn't add up to much for me or anyone to duplicate the issue. (I'm not talking a complete code dump, just enough to be able to duplicate the issue.)

Comment: It also makes no sense to use force-unwrapping (`!`) and the nil-coalescing operator (`??`) in the same expression.

Comment: Try to write code without `!`s - in the long term, you'll be glad you did

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I pass a variable from viewDidLoad to the button action?

Store the value in an instance property. Properties are global to all methods, so `viewDidLoad` can see it (to store the value in it) and the button action method can see it (to retrieve and use it).

Comment: People are allowed to say things in comments that don't answer the question; that is what a comment _is_. What they _are not_ allowed to do is be rude about each other, and I've flagged _your_ comment for that reason.